Example of $M $ and $N$ are not f.g, but $M \otimes_R N$ is f.g
Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and $M$ and $N$ $R$-modules. I know that if $M $and $N$ are finitely generated (f.g) $R$-modules, $M \otimes_R N$ is also f.g.
I wonder what would be an  example where $M $ and $N$ are not f.g, but $M \otimes_R N$ is nontheless f.g?

Zero effort question. Answers itself by looking at elementary examples that also appear on this site. See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3966925/tensor-product-mathbbq-mathbbz-otimes-m and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2761679/how-to-find-mathbbq-mathbbz-otimes-mathbbz-mathbbq - hence -1

$$\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z=0.$$
Indeed, for any positive integers $m$ and $n$, $$\frac1m\otimes \frac1n=\frac1m\otimes \frac{m}{mn}=\frac mm\otimes \frac1{mn}=0\otimes\frac1{mn}=0.$$

I like this answer best because is the most beginner-friendly., how can I see that Q/Z is not f.g?

@some_math_guy See here. On this site, you can find (almost) everything.

I have trouble with 1)  $\frac mm\otimes \frac1{mn}$, shouldn't it $\frac mm\otimes \frac1{mn}=1\otimes\frac1{mn}$?, How does the $0$ get there?

@some_math_guy I'm using that $1=0$ in $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$.


is this "$0 \otimes\frac1{mn}=0$" just $\Bbb Z$-bilinearity ?


@some_math_guy Sure, one way to see it is that $0\otimes x+0\otimes x=(0+0)\otimes x=0\otimes x$, so $0\otimes x=0$.

If $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $p,q$ are distinct primes, $M=\mathbb{Z}_{p^{\infty}}$ (the Prüfer $p$-group), and $N=\mathbb{Z}_{q^{\infty}}$, then $M\otimes N$ is trivial, hence finitely generated.

Take the power series ring $R=K[[x]]$ and $M=K$, $N={\rm Quot}(R)$.
Then $M\otimes_R N=0$, because $M$ is torsion, but $N$ is not finitely generated.

Good example, but $M$ is finitely generated; OP asks for both $M$ and $N$ to not be finitely generated.
